# impact of the single pixel in disparity

Tags: computer-vision, image-processing

Disparity essentially means the distance of a corresponding pixel in another image ( in pixels). This is clear and understood. When I looked after how the depth is related to disparity, then I found the formula

```
Base * Focal / disparity = Depth
```

This equation looks interesting, For example,  Base is 50 mm, and Focal is 2 mm  then

```
    (50*2)/2 = 50 ( for dispary 2)
    (50/2)/3 =  33.3 ( for disparity 3)
```

My question now is, just one-pixel change ( from 2nd pixel to 3rd pixel), the difference in the depth is (50 - 33.3).  I am aware there is something subpixel concept, but even then how this subpixel is still going to fulfill the gap ( 50 - 33.3 ) by means of "one single" pixel?

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Focal means something different. It is not measured in mm, but in pixel units. You need to calculate camera matrix to get the horizontal focal point and horizontal coordinate of the principal point. https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?highlight=rectification#stereocalibrate